# Why isn't my Java number input code working?

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out why isn't my code working. If I don't do it through a method and put this code in the main method then it keeps repeating. I want to ask the user for a new number every time. And then see if the number is odd or even. If odd then increase the odd count add all the numbers that the user enters. The user should be asked to enter values until the number 0 is entered.

```
package Week1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task12 {

    public void numbers() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        int oddnumbers = 0;
        do {

            int count = 0;
            count = count + i;
            System.out.println("The total is:" + count);
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("The number is Even");
            } else if (i != 9) {
                oddnumbers += i;
                System.out.println("The number is odd");
                System.out.println("the count of odd numbers is :" + oddnumbers);
            } else
                System.out.println("The number is odd");
            System.out.println("the count of odd numbers is :" + oddnumbers);

        } while (i != 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Task12 n = new Task12();
        n.numbers();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to put some more effort into formatting your question as well as elaborating on "it isn't working" (you described what you expect but what do you get instead? etc.).

Comment: Btw, `int i = sc.nextInt(); System.out.println("Enter number");` - you're reading the number before asking the user???

Comment: 1. initialise count outside of the loop
2. `i = sc.nextInt()` should be within the loop

Comment: because you are not changing the value of i

Comment: Oh dear, it is this time of the year again. This clearly looks like some Java 101 homework. Please go to your instructor and ask him/her these questions. They can explain is better and faster than we can online.

Comment: tell us what's exactly the problem , i mean what the problem wants

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have the reading of a number "`i = sc.nextInt();`" inside the loop, and the variable `count` outside, like this:

```
package Week1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task12 {

public void numbers() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);     
    int oddnumbers = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int i=0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        i = sc.nextInt();
        count = count + i;
        System.out.println("The total is:" + count);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("The number is Even");
        } else if (i != 9) {
            oddnumbers += i;
            System.out.println("The number is odd");
            System.out.println("the count of odd numbers is :" + oddnumbers);
        } else
            System.out.println("The number is odd");
        System.out.println("the count of odd numbers is :" + oddnumbers);
    } while (i != 0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Task12 n = new Task12();
    n.numbers();
}

}
```

Comment: Better to use `for (int i = sc.nextInt(); i != 0; i = sc.nextInt()) {`, or `while (true) { int i = sc.nextInt(); if (i == 0) break; ... }`, so you don't execute the body if `i == 0` immediately.

Comment: Or one could use this nasty piece of code: `while ((i = sc.nextInt()) != 0) { ... }` (no, seriously, this code is nasty. Do not use this).

Answer (score 0):

This code gives the answer to tour spec/question

> Reason for not working: You should take input inside do while loop and then check for odd.

```
 public int numbers() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = 0;
    int oddSum = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        num = sc.nextInt();
        if(num == 0) {
            break;
        } else if (num % 2 != 0) {
            oddSum += num;
        }
    } while (num != 0);
    sc.close();
    return oddSum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test n = new Test();
    System.out.println(n.numbers());
}
```

Comment: He asked why the code isn't working, not for a ready solution

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki it was my mistake...updated the answer...you can revert your voting if it is okay

Comment: you have just repeated my answer now

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki it's not your answer...that is the answer to this question...you should not say this here..being having 2k reputation